# SQL Rounding Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, rounding

I have this field I am attempting to run, but it continuously rounds the answer to 0.

```
(Select round(Count( TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.[Sender]) from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc  where [Sender] = 'agent'),2) 
/
(Select round(Count( TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc.[Sender]) from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc  where [Sender] = 'user'),2) as 'ServiceCount'
```

now this equation should essentially be 3277/3369, therefore resulting in a decimal, but I keep getting 0. I have even tried removing the the round function and multiplying the entire equation by 1.00, but it gives me 0.00

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? `[Sender]` looks like SQL Server/T-SQL?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counts are numbers, even if you round.  Do the rounding *after* the division and then round -- or better yet, convert to a decimal.

You can also eliminate the two queries, and replace it with one:

```
(Select sum(case when [Sender] = 'agent' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) /
        sum(case when [Sender] = 'user' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
 from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc
)
```

For the `round()`:

```
round( (Select sum(case when [Sender] = 'agent' then 1.0 else 0.0 end) /
               sum(case when [Sender] = 'user' then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
        from TestDN.dbo.ServiceDoc
       ), 2
     ) as ServiceCount
```

Also, only use single quotes for string and column literals (constants).  Don't use them for column names.  That leads to confusion and potentially hard-to-debug errors.